# Backup/restore to multiple removable volumes

Tags: backup, restore, optical-drive, disk-volume

I remember using old DOS software to backup an entire hard drive to a set of floppy disks - yes that long ago! With the backup target folder identified it would come up with a number of floppy disks required, then ask for them to be inserted one after another. To restore the backup you begin with the first backup of the set, it tells you that the other 'n' disks will be required and then after inserting them sequentially the backup was restored.

Now I have a large iPhotos library (~200GB), and it's mirrored in iCloud and I'm reasonably confident about that. However I want a backup. Doesn't matter how good or reliable someone else's infrastructure has been, disasters happen.

An external hard drive can make a backup of that in one bite. I don't want to use an external drive for this. Apart from other considerations it is always tempting to make use of an external drive for something else.

External removable media such as BDXL optical discs are write-once and some promise archival life spans. I would like to be able to use them as a backup destination. Of course one of these discs cannot hold the entire photo library, best capacity available now is 125GB or so. Being able to use these discs as permanent backup would be a good solution.

Does such a program exist? I have read a few roundup and review type articles and they all make much of needing to create an account and uploading everything for some software and of simply copying to a volume or a Time Machine for others.

An app that could backup a folder to multiple volumes of arbitrary size would be OK as long as these images could then be backed up/restored and then reassembled into the original folder.

Comment: The 'Industry standard' used to be [Toast Titanium](https://www.roxio.com/en/products/toast/titanium/) though I haven't used it in a decade. Having said that, you could buy a new HD for the price of the software.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin. Even without considering the price, IMO you are better off with backups on another drive. It's easier to set up, you can still make it a "one time copy" and then put it in a bunker and if its not being used a hard drive (or even better) an SSD also has a great longevity. This one for example even comes in a waterproof case: https://www.amazon.de/ADATA-Externe-wasserdicht-staubdicht-ASD700-512GU3-CYL/dp/B01N1GPDQ2/ref=sr_1_6?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=externe+ssd+512gb&qid=1623262752&sr=8-6